# I edited the users table column, so the Stripe/Cashier wont work! Any ideas?

Tags: html, mysql, laravel

After I installed the Cashier/Laravel, it edits the users tables and added many tables.

So I had to change the users table, so I rollback the users table. Then added a column and migrated it after than.

The problem here is that the Cashier package is not working anymore, any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what did you change?

Comment: i added only a column in the db using terminal. 

This Steps>>> 

> i changed the batch migration to a number that is higher then more then the other rows (migration) in the db.

> i edited the migration file in the database/migrations/ users migration files.
> then i run the rollback command
> then i migrate the db again,
> then i found that all the cashier columns r deleted, 
Now the cashier not working now

Comment: why did you do this at all? if you want to add/remove/change a column you can do that with a new migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably changing the `batch` value from the `migrations` table had something to do about it. I wouldn't recommend modifying old migrations but creating new ones to add new fields.

The Cashier migration responsible for adding those fields into the `users` table is the `2019_05_03_000001_create_customer_columns` one. Maybe an option here is to remove that row from the `migrations` table and running `php artisan migrate`.

Anyway, since you already rolled back the users table, I'd assume you could always reset your database by running `php artisan migrate:reset` (or cleaning up the database manually) and running the migrations from scratch.